# How to propagate values in one column to rows in other columns (pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have raw data in this format (the input is actually an enormous excel sheet), with multiple rows being generated due to unique values in one column, kind of like this example:

```
data = [['tom', 10, 'vanilla'], ['tom', 10, 'chocolate'], ['nick', 15, 'strawberry'], ['nick', 15, 'butter pecan'], ['nick', 15, 'mint chocolate chip'], ['juli', 14, 'strawberry'], ['juli', 14, 'chocolate'], ['juli', 14, 'vanilla']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Favorite Ice Cream'])
```

but I need to create a dataframe from the raw data above in this format below, where the last column is spread into rows and the duplicate rows are eliminated:

```
data2 = [['tom', 10, 'vanilla', 'chocolate', '', ''], ['nick', 15, 'butter pecan', '', 'strawberry', 'mint chocolate chip'], ['juli', 14, 'vanilla', 'chocolate', 'strawberry', '']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Favorite Vanilla-based Ice Cream',  'Favorite Chocolate-based Ice Cream',  'Favorite Berry Ice Cream', 'Favorite Other Ice Cream'])
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What values do you expect in the `'Favorite X Ice Cream'` columns in `df2`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `pivot` and a mapping dict:

```
mapping = {'Vanilla': ['vanilla', 'butter pecan'],
           'Chocolate': ['chocolate'],
           'Berry': ['strawberry']}

reverse_mapping = {v: k for k, l in mapping.items() for v in l}

df['X-based'] = df['Favorite Ice Cream'].map(reverse_mapping).fillna('Other')

out = df.pivot(index=['Name', 'Age'],
               columns='X-based',
               values='Favorite Ice Cream') \
        .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index().fillna('')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Name  Age       Berry  Chocolate                Other       Vanilla
0  juli   14  strawberry  chocolate                            vanilla
1  nick   15  strawberry             mint chocolate chip  butter pecan
2   tom   10              chocolate                            vanilla
```

Comment: @One2three. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: Hello Corralien. I get this error with your script: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape